# Jquery method executed several time

Tags: javascript, jquery, comet

I'm trying to implement simple Comet chat example and for this I implemented Long polling which calls itself recursively every 30 seconds.

When pressing on button I want another ajax request to send new data on Server using POST.

For now I just put alert to this function to trigger click event

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var polling = function poll(){
    $("#postMessage").click(function () {
    alert("request");
    });
    $.ajax({ dataType: 'json',url: "CometServlet", success: function(data){

            if (data !=null){
      $('#message').append(data.sender+" : " + data.message+"<br />");
            }
    }, complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
}
$(document).ready(polling)

</script>
```

And my HTML is like this:

```
<div>
   <input type="button" id="postMessage" value="post Message">
</div>
<div id ="message" name="message"></div>
```

When I click on button my alert is shown several times. Why? How can I solve it?

Comment: How are you waiting for 30 seconds? That's not what `timeout` is for, if that was what you were thinking. Are you sure the extra `alert`s aren't just because you call poll immediately after every ajax request completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dave mentions, that's not what the `timeout` option is for. Try something using `setTimeout` instead. Also, you're mixing your polling logic and your `click` handler (I think). Here's how you would separate them:

```
function poll() {
    $.ajax({ 
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "CometServlet", 
        success: function(data){
            if (data !=null){
                $('#message').append(data.sender+" : " + data.message+"<br />");
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout(poll, 30000);
        }
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#postMessage").click(function () {
        alert("request");
    });

    poll();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VyGTh/

Answer (score 2):

In your code after every Ajax call you re-bind click event to #postMessage and that's why you had couple of alert messages. You need to bind click only once in page load. You can fix it by doing something like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var polling = function poll(){
    $.ajax({ dataType: 'json',url: "CometServlet", 
           success: function(data){
                if (data !=null){
                    $('#message').append(data.sender+" : " + data.message+"<br />");
                }
           }, 
           complete: poll, 
           timeout: 30000 
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Now Click only binds one time
    $("#postMessage").click(function () {
         alert("request");
    });
    polling();
});

</script>
```